# Rally add a list of Changes to a Changeset. Using Java Toolkit for Rally REST API

Tags: java, rest, rally

I have a list of Changes (in String format) and i now need to add this to a Changeset.
The Changeset is already attached to the Artifact, but i am having trouble adding the Changes to the Changeset.

Any help would be great! 
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Changes is a field on Changeset, it seems reasonable to be able to update a Changeset object and set Changes to collection of Change refs.  However, the Rally web service API wants things a little differently.

Changeset is a required field on a Change object, so you can't create the Change object in Rally without giving it a Changeset ref.  And that's exactly how you add Changes to a Changeset.

Assuming you have a Changeset ref in a String called csRef (e.g. "https://rally.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.33/changeset/223534.js"), the following code will create a Change object (Changeset and PathAndFilename are the required fields) in Rally and attach it to that Changeset:

```
JsonObject newChange = new JsonObject();
newChange.addProperty("Changeset", csRef);
newChange.addProperty("PathAndFilename", "a/b/c");  

CreateRequest cRequest = new CreateRequest("change", newChange);
CreateResponse cResponse = restApi.create(cRequest);
String cRef = cResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString();
System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", cRef));
```

You probably already know this, but the web service api docs, which specify which fields are required to create objects, are here: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey thanks that helped a lot! but i am having trouble making a link out of the entry any suggestions? thanks